# Ayuda con el funcionamiento de una matriz en c#

Tags: c#, matrices

Mi programa representa una empresa de ciberseguridad, esta en proceso aun, hay muchas cosas que agregarle.

Mi principal problema ahora mismo es con la matriz, quiero incorporar una matriz para que puedan venir muchas personas y realizar el programa, y que sus datos (nombre, apellido y edad) queden guardados en dicha matriz y al final del programa se impriman.

Pero si hago la matriz con el for i<3 me pide las 3 veces juntas, yo quiero que la matriz funcione asi:
Pide datos -> Ejecuta y finaliza programa (Se guarda datos de persona que realizo el programa).

Dicha persona se va y viene otra para hacer el programa, Pide datos -> Ejecuta y finaliza (se guardan datos). Y si viene una persona mas y accede a la matriz que se impriman los datos de estas dos personas.
Aquí el progama:

```
using System;

namespace PlaterotiNuevo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              // Inico funcionamiento de Matríz.

                String[] Nombres;
                Nombres = new String[3];
                int[] Edad = new int[3];

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIngrese su nombre y apellido por 
                    favor:\n");
                    Nombres[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nIngrese su edad:\n");
                    Edad[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < Nombres.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Nombres[j] + " con " + Edad[j] + " 
                        años.");
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El programa iria entre la declaracion de la matriz y la impresion de la misma

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Hola, te adjunto el link de otro foro donde me explico mejor:https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/C-sharp/1752444-Ayuda-con-matriz-en-mi-programa.html#i1752529

Answer (score 0):

Lo que propongo como solución es lo siguiente, y hay varios matices en relación al código inicial con los que logramos un código más funcional.

```
using System;

namespace PlaterotiNuevo
{

struct regPersona
{
    public string Nombre;
    public int Edad;
}

static void Main ()
{
    const int NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS = 3;

    // Creamos la matriz
    regPersona[] Persona = new regPersona[NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS];
    
    // Albergará el número de Personas que hacen la entrevista.
    int nPersonas = 0;
    // Para saber si queremos otra entrevista. Inicialmente sí, por eso
    // se inicializa con "S" 
    string otraEntrevista = "S";
    
    while (otraEntrevista.ToUpper() == "S")
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese su nombre y apellido por favor: ");
        Persona[nPersonas].Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ingrese su edad: ");
        Persona[nPersonas].Edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        // ---- Código HACER ENTREVISTA
        
        
        // ----
        
        nPersonas++; // Incrementamos ya que una persona 
                     // hizo la entrevista.
        
        // Si ya alcanzamos el máximo número permitido de
        // entrevistas, salimos del bucle.
        if (nPersonas == NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS) break;
        
        // Para terminar debemos saber si hay otra persona
        // preparada para hacer la entrevista.
        Console.Write("\nIniciar otra entrevista (S/N): ");
        otraEntrevista = Console.ReadLine();
    } 

    // Imprimimos el arreglo y lo recorremos según las Personas
    // que hicieron la entrevista.
    Console.WriteLine("\n-- Personas Entrevistadas --" );
    for (int j = 0; j < nPersonas; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Persona[j].Nombre + " con " + 
                          Persona[j].Edad.ToString() + " años.");
    }
}

}
```

He creado un tipo *regPersona* donde ya incluimos el Nombre y la Edad; de esta forma sólo tendrás un array de tipo *regPersona* en lugar de dos arrays independientes pero relacionados. Crear un tipo personalizado nos permite un código más compacto y legible.

Observa también que he creado una constante NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS que nos dice el número máximo de entrevistas que se pueden realizar y que nos marcará el tamaño del array.

Otro punto es crear una variable '*otraEntrevista*' que controla si hay una nueva entrevista o no; y en base a ella rularemos en un bucle para solicitar los datos a la persona y hacer la entrevista. Y también nos creamos una variable llamada *nPersonas* que nos va a ir contando las personas que han hecho la entrevista; esto nos permitirá al final recorrer el array para mostrar los datos.

Espero que sea la solución que ibas buscando.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, estoy hace un mes queriendo solucionar esto y no he podido tu comentario ha sido la clave para resolver mi programa!!!!!